# How to change the speed of an audio and then put it back to its normal speed

Tags: audio, audacity, pitch

Maybe it's too simple a question but I can't figure out how to do this.

I would like to regulate the speed in the same way as in a turntable with a speed regulator (pitch) but it is impossible for me.

In Audacity, in the "change speed" effect I put a change percentage at -45,000 and apply the changes.

[image]

I save that audio and open it again. Now I want to bring the audio back to the same speed that it had before it slowed down. As easy as opening the tool again and instead of setting it to -45, now setting it to +45, right? Well, it's not like that, if I set it to +45 the audio speed is still slower than before it was slowed down.

[image]

It starts to be heard at its speed if I turn it up to +80, but of course this is not the solution, I would like it to be exact.

I have been handling audio programs for a short time and I have not found any tool to modify the speed in the style of how it is regulated on a record player. What do you recommend? in Audacity what is happening? Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't read the Spanish[?] properly, but this is simple arithmetic. If you multiply 100 by 0.55 You get 55. If you then multiply 55 by 1.45 you get 79.75, not 100.

Comment: As Tetsujin explains, this is a math question, not an audio question. In order to cancel out multiplying by 55/100 (0.55 or -45%), you have to multiply by 100/55, which is about 1.818, or +81.8%